# How to read folders which only have specific subfolder named in node js?

Tags: node.js, readdir

I have the following directory structure. The main directory has folders (ex. main_A) and some of them have a subfolder named "foo" but the other doesn't.

```
main
        |__main_A/foo
        |__main_B/a
        |__main_C/b
        |__main_D/foo
        |__main_E/foo
        |__main_F/c
```

Currently, I am using `fsPromise.readdir()` to read the files. My question is simply how to read and dive into only folders including `foo` subfolder?

Eventually, I need to read all files in the `foo` folder.

```js
async function readFooFolder() {
  try {
    const pathProd = 'C:\\main';
    const fileList = await fsPromise.readdir(pathProd);
    console.log(fileList);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attempt to read the "foo" subdir for each directory in `fileList`. If the subddir does not exist for that directory, then an error with code `ENOENT` will be thrown.

```
const path = require('path');
async function readFooFolder() {
  try {
    const pathProd = 'C:\\main';
    const fileList = await fsPromise.readdir(pathProd);
    for (const subDir of fileList) {
      const fooDir = path.join(pathProd, subDir, 'foo');
      try {
        const fooFiles = await fsPromise.readdir(fooDir);
        // do something with fooFiles...
      } catch (fooErr) {
        if (fooErr.code != 'ENOENT') {
          console.error(fooErr);
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! It perfectly works. Thank buddy!